# Mandrill API Content-Transfer-Encoding

Tags: email

Mandrill's email is failing in google email tester because of quoted_printable. So how can I change mandrill's Content-Transfer-Encoding from 'quoted_pritable' to '7bit'?

Comment: Could you show the failure reported by Google's tester?

Comment: Google's tester shows 'No structured data present' because of <script type=3D"application/ld+json">. And when I change from type=3D"application/ld+json" to type="application/ld+json", it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit of 998 characters for a single line in mail and also mail should not contain non-ascii characters. That is why mail's content-transfer-encoding was changing from 7bit to quoted-printable.